# Catch Error details on IIS Custom Error Page

Tags: javascript, xml, iis, custom-error-pages

Using web.config I configured IIS to redirect 500 errors to a custom page that is in my application.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="500" />
        <error statusCode="500" path="/Pages/ErrorPages/CustomError.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

This is working perfectly and it is redirecting to the mentioned classic asp page when there is a 500 error.

Now I want to capture the error details such as file path and line number from my custom error page, which shows on the standard error page when we set "Send errors To Browser" to TRUE and Error page features to "Detailed errors"

What are the methods I can use to solve this by configuring IIS and using javascript/jquery

[image: Send errors To Browser]
[image: Error page features]
[image: Sample standerd detailed error]

Comment: You could add some code to the customer error page that creates a log entry into your database containing some of that data.  But as far as switching back and forth from a custom page to display to screen instead .. I'm not sure .. because isn't that done in the web.config ?  Other than having some code that does an IF/THEN to select WHICH web.config to use ... and have it switch to the one that display to screen instead of the Custom 500 error ..something like that might work perhaps.

Comment: Another setting in web.config is custom error mode. You can set it to off to make YSOD output detailed error message like file pathe and line number. `<system.web><customErrors mode="Off" />`

Comment: @BruceZhang I added <customErrors> section to the config file using IIS Configuration editor. How can I  capture the error details from my custom page? How can I check if the details have been sent to the browser?

Comment: `How can I capture the error details from my custom page? ` Do you mean that you want custom error page show error message? If so, you need to write code to capture exception. Then post on custom error page, not set on IIS.

Comment: @BruceZhang Exactly. 
I need details such as Physical Path and Error Code etc. 
This is for a classic ASP project and the requirement is to redirect any 500 error to a custom error page from IIS settings. It could be a code-level issue or any other issue that cannot classify under other error codes. So I guess capturing exceptions and redirecting to an error page from code will not fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As the **Detailed Error** overrides the content of my custom error page, I came up with a different approach to overcome my problem.

I Enabled **Failed Request Tracking Rule** on IIS and it creates a log folder inside *inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles*

[image]

Inside that folder, It creates a separate error log (XML) for each Error.
That XML has a format like below.

```
<failedRequest url="" siteId="" appPoolId="" processId="" verb="GET" remoteUserName="" userName="" tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" authenticationType="anonymous" activityId="" failureReason="STATUS_CODE" statusCode="500" triggerStatusCode="500" timeTaken="" xmlns:freb="">
<Event>
<System></System><EventData></EventData><RenderingInfo></RenderingInfo><ExtendedTracingInfo></ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event>
<System></System><EventData></EventData><RenderingInfo></RenderingInfo><ExtendedTracingInfo></ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
...
...
</failedRequest
```

I looped through Event tags and Selected the one with
***Event>System>Level*** is equal to 2.
That is the event it shows as an Error when you preview the XML.
Then you can read ***Event>EventData*** for Error LineNumber and Description.

From my custom error page, I requested information using an XHR call and stored it in a hidden field until required.